# Query to count each selected answer of question from array of forms with mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to using MongoDB queries.

I would like to count the number of selected answers based on the question.

Here is an example of data I'm trying to process:

```
  {
    "_id": "910ef391-bc06-4fda-80c5-c6a6d9bcXXXX",
    "book": {
      "register": [
        {
          "questions": [
            {
              "id": "87b8c60c-9c9e-41d1-a52a-588400deXXXX",
              "name": "Question A",
              "answers": [
                {
                  "_id": 1,
                  "label": "Answer 1",
                  "selected": true
                },
                {
                  "_id": 2,
                  "label": "Answer 2",
                  "selected": false
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": "55b8c60c-9c9e-41d1-a52a-588400deXXXX",
              "name": "Question B",
              "answers": [
                {
                  "_id": 1,
                  "label": "Answer 1",
                  "selected": true
                },
                {
                  "_id": 2,
                  "label": "Answer 2",
                  "selected": false
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "120ef391-bc06-4fda-80c5-c6a6d9bcXXXX",
    "book": {
      "register": [
        {
          "questions": [
            {
              "id": "99b8c60c-9c9e-41d1-a52a-588400deXXXX",
              "name": "Question A",
              "answers": [
                {
                  "_id": 1,
                  "label": "Answer 1",
                  "selected": true
                },
                {
                  "_id": 2,
                  "label": "Answer 2",
                  "selected": false
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Here is the expected result:

```
[
  {
    "Answer 1": 2
  }
]
```

I would like to count the number of selected answers to question A.

I've tried something, but it returns no `document found`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$book.register.questions",
      questions: {
        $push: "$book.register.questions"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "questions.name": "Question A"
    }
  }
])
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

A bit long query.

1. `$match` - Filter the document with dot notation to find the document containing "Question A".
2. `$unwind` - Deconstruct `book.register` array into multiple documents.
3. `$unwind` - Deconstruct `book.register.questions` array into multiple documents.
4. `$unwind` - Deconstruct `book.register.questions.answers` array into multiple documents.
5. `$group` - Group by `book.register.questions.answers.label` and perform conditional total sum based on `book.register.questions.answers.selected` value. Add 1 if it is true.
6. `$group` - Group by `null`. This aims to combine all the documents into a single document by pushing the answer label and count into the `answers` array.
7. `$replaceWith` - Replace the input document to convert from the `answers` array into key-value pair.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "book.register.questions.name": "Question A"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$book.register"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$book.register.questions"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$book.register.questions.answers"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$book.register.questions.answers.label",
      count: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: {
            if: {
              $eq: [
                "$book.register.questions.answers.selected",
                true
              ]
            },
            then: 1,
            else: 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      answers: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id",
          v: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: {
      $arrayToObject: "$answers"
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mqokB60L9Ym)

Comment: Thanks you very much for your answer !! But the first pipeline seems not filter by "Question A" because the result are following: [
  {
    "Answer 1": 3,
    "Answer 2": 0
  }
] So The request takes into account all the questions and therefore does not filter on "Question A". The result expected is [
  {
    "Answer 1": 2,
    "Answer 2": 0
  }
]
Can you help me on this? Thank you a lot !

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Good to see you find the answer. Yes, in case I put the `$match` stage at first, is to filter the document contains Question A in the array. Then I shall also place the `$match` criteria after `$unwind: "$book.register.questions.answers"` stage. Which the `$match` stage don't have to repeat by following your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It works !!!
Just move the first `$match` pipeline after the `$unwind` pipeline: `"$book.register.questions"`.
@Yong Shun => Thank you very much for your answer, your reactivity and your quality of response !

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$book.register"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$book.register.questions"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "book.register.questions.name": "Question A"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$book.register.questions.answers"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$book.register.questions.answers.label",
      count: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: {
            if: {
              $eq: [
                "$book.register.questions.answers.selected",
                true
              ]
            },
            then: 1,
            else: 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      answers: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id",
          v: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: {
      $arrayToObject: "$answers"
    }
  }
])
```